# How to upload provisioning profile to iPhone

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I want my tester to test my iPhone app. I add his UDID in devices and add provisioning profile for him device. But how can I upload this profile to him iPhone? Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He can just drag the profile file onto his device via iTunes. But afaik, the profile also installs itself (at least if you use OverTheAir distribution) from the embedded.mobilepovision file within your .ipa file when installing the app on the device. This might also be valid if you just drag it on iTunes...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a good job of monitoring your testers and builds, I would consider using [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com). It will handle all of the provisioning for your apps. It will also give you instant feedback as to who has opened your notifications, install progress, what version they are running. They are free right now, and you simply cannot beat how easy it is to use. For developers, by developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can send it to him, and have him drag it to his device via Xcode or iTunes. But you also have to provide him with your developer certificate that Apple gives you and your key. It could work, but you'll more likely end up with headaches since it takes developers hours trying to install the certificates themselves, never mind for other people. If possible, I would try to get it approved first, but don't launch it, and send your tester a promo code.